# Error in creating png with imagecreate in php

Tags: php, imagecreatefrompng

I am working on creating captcha and this is my script for creating captcha image.

```
    header("Content-type: image/png");
$width              = 100;
$height             = 40;
$im                 = ImageCreate($width, $height);

$bg                 = ImageColorAllocate($im, 250, 250, 250);

$border             = ImageColorAllocate($im, 191, 191, 191);
ImageRectangle($im, 0, 0, $width - 1, $height - 1, $border);

$text               = base64_decode($GLOBALS["captcha_akey"]);

$textcolor          = ImageColorAllocate($im,0,5,5);

$font               = 3;

$font_width         = ImageFontWidth($font);
$font_height        = ImageFontHeight($font);

$text_width         = $font_width * strlen($text);

$position_center    = ceil(($width - $text_width) / 2);

$text_height        = $font_height;

$position_middle    = ceil(($height - $text_height) / 2);

ImageString($im, $font, $position_center, $position_middle, $text, $textcolor);

ImagePNG($im);
```

Captcha displaying correctly but at the top of captcha I found this error.

```
    �PNG  IHDRd(u�� PLTE������IDAT8�퓻 �0DU�M�R�Y"�*=���)C)T�"��pXH���$����|�˟�$�9N����$獌�@�54�i[ -Hi\ku7��&Y���АLA�h;�Ah�^u�*���5 I:;���\�pd;��;ߓ�6b�(���'P�SY���IEND�B`�
```

Comment: Are you sending the Content-Type header with something like `header('Content-Type: image/png');` when you're displaying the image? Without it, it will just display as text like the "error" you've shown.

Comment: yes I have given that before the script starts

Comment: Can you show the code that actually displays the image? Perhaps a call to `readfile()`, or a simple `echo`? Also, is there a second call somewhere above the `<img />` tag that calls a different image-creation code?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your header (header("Content-type: image/png");) has been sent in the html content. All headers must be outputed before anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by enabling the gd extention in php.ini

uncomment this line in php.ini file: `extension=php_gd2.dll` (remove the leading ;)

to find your php.ini file, create the following file and upload to server and run in browser.

```
    <?php
phpinfo();
?>
```

it will show a line like,
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /usr/local/lib
 and 
Loaded Configuration File   /usr/local/lib/php.ini